# Loop over table rows that have a data attribute

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html-table

I have a table that shows product codes whereby the customer can enter the quantity they desire.

```
    <tr data-code="TEST1" data-description="Test Product (EACH)" data-whqc="" >
      <td>
        TEST1
      </td>
      <td>
        Test Product (EACH)
      </td>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input name="qty" type="text" class="qty" maxlength="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

There are many rows in the table and I want to send this data to an AJAX page so that I can add these products to the cart.

How can I loop over all rows of a table that have the `data-*` elements, add them to an array a well as the qty input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = [];
    $("#tbl").find("tr[data-code]").each(function () {
        var qty = parseFloat($(this).find(".qty").val()) || 0;
        if (qty > 0) {
            array[array.length] = {
                Code: $(this).attr("data-code"),
                Description: $(this).attr("data-description"),
                Whqc: $(this).attr("data-whqc"),
                Qty: qty
            };
        }
    });
```

jsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7kykjg2m/1/

Explanation:

1. Create empty array
2. Iterate over all TR elements that have the `data-code` attribute
3. Parse qty into a float (I use float because sometimes qty can be fractional, like litres of oil), but use `|| 0` to set `qty` to 0 if quantity is blank/null or `NaN`.
4. If quantity is more than 0, add the item to the array as an object using JSON
5. When done, pass array data to server/service using `$.ajax()` or whatever, but you didn't give details on that side of things, so didn't show code for this.